# Microsoft AD Login via Cognito shows broken page when type wrong email

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-cognito

I created a federated sign in with Azure AD via Cognito and works fine.

The problem happens when I type an email that does not belong to the domain configured in Azure AD, it shows a blank broken page. I want to know if it is possible to configure any place to maybe show a friendly message that email is wrong or does not belong to the domain.